# C# how to read single item in node xml

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces, key

I have xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><SENT_110 xmlns:ns2="http://www.mf.gov.pl/SENT/2017/01/18/STypes.xsd" xmlns="http://www.mf.gov.pl/SENT/2017/01/18/SENT_110.xsd"><SentNumber>SENT20180416000032</SentNumber><KeyNumber><ns2:SenderKey>KS-28YM</ns2:SenderKey><ns2:RecipientKey>KR-52DH</ns2:RecipientKey><ns2:CarrierKey>KD-48WW</ns2:CarrierKey></KeyNumber>
```

I want to read in separate SenderKey, RecipientKey & CarrierKey.
When i use this code:

```
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(file);
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(reader);
        XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", xmlDoc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);
          XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/ns:SENT_110/ns:KeyNumber", nsmgr);
          foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
          {
            key = node.InnerText;
            MessageBox.Show(key);
          }
```

i've got something like this: KS-28YMKR-52DHKD-48WW, without any separate between key.
How i could read only one key?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following XPath:

```
"/ns:SENT_110/ns:KeyNumber/*"
```

It will return all nested nodes to you.

Answer (score 0):

If the structure of the XML is fixed it is rather easy by using `XDocument`:

```
var xmlText = "<SENT_110 xmlns:ns2=\"http://www.mf.gov.pl/SENT/2017/01/18/STypes.xsd\" xmlns=\"http://www.mf.gov.pl/SENT/2017/01/18/SENT_110.xsd\"><SentNumber>SENT20180416000032</SentNumber><KeyNumber><ns2:SenderKey>KS-28YM</ns2:SenderKey><ns2:RecipientKey>KR-52DH</ns2:RecipientKey><ns2:CarrierKey>KD-48WW</ns2:CarrierKey></KeyNumber></SENT_110>";
var xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlText);
var nodes = xml.Descendants();
var senderKey = nodes.First(d => d.Name.ToString().EndsWith("SenderKey")).Value;
var recipientKey = nodes.First(d => d.Name.ToString().EndsWith("RecipientKey")).Value;
var carrierKey = nodes.First(d => d.Name.ToString().EndsWith("CarrierKey")).Value;
```

See [HERE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kSwQfD) for a working snippet. If this is just a part of a bigger XML or the structure can be different maybe some more complex searching is needed.

Comment: It works, when variable xmlText contains this xml. If I try load xml file, I got error: "System.Xml.XmlException:Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."

Comment: How did you load the XML file? `XDocument.Load`?

Comment: Yes i use XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\admin\file.xml");

Comment: @miszczu Then it seems your XML-file is actually invalid. Is the example in the question a complete XML-File? Because that one is missing a closing tag I added manually...

Comment: In this examle is only part of xml-file. Here is complete file: https://ufile.io/ewsdi

Comment: Could you show me part of declaration & load file to parse? I stil got error "System.Xml.XmlException:Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1

Comment: @miszczu There is nothing special. I just replaced `XDocument.Parse(xmlText)` with `XDocument.Load(@"PATH_TO_DOWNLOADED_XML")` and it still worked fine...

Comment: Thanks. Of course this code works perfectly. I just made stupid mistakes in xdocument.Load.